# How can poll results be verified?

Tags: public-opinion, polling

Politicians often base their policy decisions on what they perceive as the public opinion, as revealed in opinion polls. This apparently puts a lot of power at the hands of the companies running the polls (e.g. by Internet panels). Theoretically, a polling company can tweak the outcome of opinion polls in order to affect the policy decision. Since the pool of participants in the poll is usually kept secret, I do not see how such a tweak could be revealed.

1. Is there a way by which a person ordering a poll from a polling company verify that the outcomes indeed represent genuine opinions of poll participants, and not tweaked by the company?
2. Were there incidents of polling companies that were caught deliberately lying about poll outcomes?

Comment: Polling is generally done by non government groups and how you verify each poll will be different based on who is doing it.

Comment: I am particularly interested in commercial polling companies.

Comment: I guess one could ask different polling companies and see if (within the margin of error) they come up with consistent results.

Comment: Note that #1 isn't an either-or. It's entirely possible for people to fill out surveys disingenuously and for the pollster to accurately report those responses. This data isn't tweaked by the pollster, yet has no relationship to real opinions. A poll with results that don't reflect reality may be due to methodological or sampling issues; I'd expect it's only rarely indicative of outright fraud on behalf of the pollster.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "I'd expect it's only rarely indicative of outright fraud on behalf of the pollster." Why not? Because humans are good (on average)? Or because it's so difficult to get polls right that almost everyone gets it wrong anyway?

Comment: this question is currently getting vote(s) to close as off topic but because we have a [polling] tag here I believe that it is on topic.

Comment: Since polling is a huge part of modern politics I think the question belongs here even if it is not about politics per se.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You are right, there are other reasons for wrong poll results, such as non-professional sampling. But to keep the question focused, I asked only about deliberate modification of results by the polling company.

Comment: A commercial polling company depends on its reputation to get orders for new polls. So the benefit from producing a few misleading ones rarely justifies the negative effects of being blamed for unreliable results. On the other hand, political polls do aim to promote certain point of view, boost a candidate, raise the spirits of voters, etc. Obama-Romney first debate was instructive in this sense, as each one cam with his own list of polls, supporting the economic policies contradictory to those of the opponent.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Because fraud is illegal and not at all conducive to the business model of a polling company that wants to remain in business.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie If people cannot tell the difference between intentionally adjusting the results or simply working sloppily that hardly would make a difference in practice. I guess this is what this question is asking about. How do we know that polling companies do not cheat. If we cannot know it doesn't matter if it's illegal or not.

Comment: As another wrench in the works, how the questions are worded can make a difference. Two polling companies can poll on the same topic but get different results just based on how they phrased the question. One example would be [asking about the Affordable Care Act vs. asking about Obamacare](https://news.gallup.com/opinion/polling-matters/169541/name-affordable-care-act-obamacare.aspx).

Comment: @EngineerToast true, but this can be controlled by the person ordering the poll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like any other study, you can repeat the survey to verify it. If you ask the same questions to the same population you should get similar results.  This form of replication is how one has confidence that a survey was done correctly.

Of course simple replication isn't often done. But for many questions there will be multiple polls. Polling companies have much more to lose by being caught cheating than they could gain. By analogy, If I ask my doctor for advice, he could lie (perhaps so I return to him for his profit) but if he is caught lying he could lose his career. Likewise a polling company that is caught would not be trusted again and would go bust.

There are no examples that I know of, of a polling company changing their results to manipulate politicians.  However there are examples of pollsters apparently manipulating results in order to profit from betting markets ([see this](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-were-preemptively-banning-a-pollster-and-not-banning-another/)) or just [making up results](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/my-own-suspicions-about-research-2000/) completely (because they make money from selling the poll results).

Comment: *Like any other study, you can repeat the survey to verify it* True in most fields, but in this case, I am not sure that it is.  I'd be surprised it you could re-ask the Q from the same sample *without* expecting some kind of difference (akin to priming effects in psychology).  And a big part of polling is picking a sample in the first place.  For the rest, the answer seems solid enough:  a polling company that got caught would have a lot to lose.

Comment: Interesting examples, thanks!

Comment: "Of course often this isn't done". YMMV. For important enough questions, they're often polled by multiple companies. Which is the polsci equivalent of multiple groups replicating an experiment. Yes, there will be some differences due to variation in methodology, sampling etc.

Comment: @Fizz Importantly, the variations you'd expect to see in a "good" sample can be modelled statistically as well. Hence the "95% confidence for plus or minus 3% on a 50-50 question asked to 1000 people" standard.

Comment: I was going to link that 538 article on Research 2000, but you've already got it.  Also relevant from them: https://fivethirtyeight.com/tag/strategic-vision/

Answer (score 15):

The general solution is multiple, independent polling organizations. If the results of multiple polls are roughly consistent with each other, they can be considered as reliable as possible given the limitations of polling (e.g. it can be hard to get a representative sample, and poll answers don't always reflect what people actually think or will do).

As mentioned above, they have to be independent. If there's collusion among polling organizations, all bets are off. In practice there will be enough polling organizations that this is not likely. But the conspiracy-minded may envision that all the left-leaning pollsters will collude, as will all the right-leaning. Liberals will reference the first set of polls, conservatives the second, and they'll each point to the consistency among their polls as conclusive.

But if we then take a birds-eye view of all of this and see wildly differing results, it would indicate that something is going wrong somewhere. It will take a non-partisan investigation to disentangle the fraud.

Comment: For election polls one can check who came nearest to the actual true result. This would give something to measure accuracy of such polls and maybe insights into which organization had the best polling methodology. One difficulty is accurately predicting the turnout.

Comment: That's true, but relatively useless. Usually we're interested in the results of polls before the election, as they can use it in their campaign strategy.

Comment: And just because the organization got it right before this election, it doesn't mean they'll be as good the next time. It could have been a fluke, or bad actors could take over. Of course, there are organizations with decades of history, like Gallup.

Comment: Polling companies often boast of successfully predicting things like election or referendum results; this is done because it's good advertising. Generally you would assume that a company whose past performance was good would be better in future than one whose past performance was bad; this is true even with semi-random things like statistical sampling.

Comment: @StuartF Yet many reputable polls predicted Clinton would beat Trump in 2016 -- polling is hard. 538.com uses multiple polls to improve their accuracy.

Comment: @Barmar Polling is hard if you expect it to be magic. The Clinton-Trump national polls were pretty good; they were off by a percent or two. It's just that Wikipedia (Statewide opinion polling for the 2016 United States presidential election) lists 134 electoral votes as too close to call after polling. That's not bad polls; that's reality being impossible.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way by which a person ordering a poll from a polling
> company verify that the outcomes indeed represent genuine opinions of
> poll participants, and not tweaked by the company?

You can ask.

Often raw poll results are tweaked, in an effort to make them more accurate, to fit a voter turnout model or some other model of how their survey sample compared to the true demographics of the population in dimensions relevant to the outcome of the poll. When this is done, usually the polling company will provide the raw data as well, upon request, to the person who commissioned the poll.

This said, it is unfortunately true that people can lie, and you have no real way of knowing otherwise if they do. You have to rely on the reputation of the polling firm and insider whistleblowers.

In cases where polls are used to manipulate public opinion and politicians, the more common approach is to do polls with fairly small sample sizes, multiple times, and to read "push poll" language to survey respondents before the actual question is asked (without disclosing that fact), and then to only report publicly the most extreme outlier results with survey samples that are greatly skewed from the overall population (e.g. having proportionately far more people of one political party than there are in the population surveyed).

Outright intentional faking of poll numbers, especially to someone paying for a poll, in an effort to make it less accurate, is very rare.

> Were there incidents of polling companies that were caught
> deliberately lying about poll outcomes?

I can't think of any prominent examples of this happening. But I'm not omniscient.

Comment: "In cases where polls are used to manipulate public opinion and politicians, the more common approach is to do polls..." But why all that effort if you could ... simply make up the results if you want a skewed result? Is it to fool insiders who might otherwise reveal the scam? Or to convince yourself?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Because even sleazy pollsters have some standards of integrity and don't go into that business if they don't. They are aiming for the misleading but true data points which aren't outright illegal fraud. They could just make up random results without polling anyone too if they really just wanted to defraud people. Or, a politician or lobbyist could cut out the middle man and make up the polling company as well as the results. But most people are not George Santos a.k.a. Anthony Devolder.

Comment: Ah I see. Not outright criminals but also not saints. Somewhat corrupted, most probably trying to simply deliver what they think it is that their customers want from them and not taking the truth too serious. But still if you do the things you mention one can also simply ask people unbiasedly first and then simply "correct" the results to your liking. Same effect, same thing really.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution "Not outright criminals but also not saints. Somewhat corrupted, most probably trying to simply deliver what they think it is that their customers want from them and not taking the truth too serious." Precisely.

Comment: What do you mean by "to read "push poll" language "?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi For example, poll taker states: "Trump is the most popular Republican of all time and saved our nation from COVID and nuclear war. Biden has been accused of corruption and slurs his speech regularly. In a head to head race between Trump and Biden, who would you vote for in the 2024 general election for President?" The language before the question would be the "push poll language." It is especially powerful for questions about less high profile political contests.

Answer (score 1):

If the topic is really important to you or your organisation, you go to a busy street with a clip board and ask a few dozen / hundred people their opinion. It's not that hard. Having done lots of political outreach work, I estimate that you can get at least a dozen answers per hour, depending on the amount/type of question you want to ask maybe up to 30.

If the result diverges radically from what the other poll says, you will need to ask yourself why. There are many reasons other than fraud. Here some knowledge of statistics will come in handy, but you don't need that much for some basic analysis. The most important question is to ask yourself of what group the people you asked were representative.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is any method which will give you an accurate representation of what people want.

Even in an election, you have (at least) the issue that not everybody votes, and this can lead to a big change between the overall sentiment and that expressed by the people who actually voted. Depending on the type of vote, there may also be issues with not being presented with a choice you actually want, or being able to express your second choice, and so on. And in complex elections there can be issues with gerrymandering.

In polls, you have a relatively small sample, sometimes with an inherent bias (people who actually want to spend time answering a poll are not necessarily representative of the whole population, even if one tries to build a sample representative of the whole population). Also people lie.

Most polling companies will actually adjust their polls to try to get to something which is closer to reality. For polls which try to predict election/vote results, polling companies will use their past experience of the difference between raw poll results and actual results (which are affected by representativity of the sample, the people who actually vote, the final vote of the “undecided”, and in some cases the fact that people will not admit to want to vote for a given candidate or choice, but will do so in the secret of the election booth.

The issue is that this “correction” is rarely accurate, and different polling companies are known to over or underestimate the correction (they all have a bias).

Actual votes or elections will give you a much wider sample of what people think, and are in many cases the binding result. But that does not mean that the result of the vote is actually a true representation of what the whole population actually thinks, just a representation of what **the people who voted** think.

But most politicians will not really do things based on opinion polls. The good ones will do things based on what is good for the population as a whole (or at least what they think it is). Most will just try to do what they said they would do in their election pledges/manifestos: they are supposed to have a “popular mandate” to do what they said they would.

Of course, not all of them do, for varied reasons.